# how to "slow" down the execution of code blocks

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel, python, pdf

on OSX 10.13.4 with emacs 25.3 and org-mode 9.1.12. Python is 3.5.2 with matplotlib 2.2.2

I am trying to find a way to have org-mode babel for python to slow down in some of the points of my code otherwise some matplotlib plot do not always get inserted in the final produced pdf.
I have tried with `time.sleep(nb_seconds)` in my python code but it does not solve the problem.

Minimal example:

```
* import necessary modules and make plot with data

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session jk :exports results 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make the data
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 50)
y = np.sin(x)
'x is \n{0}\n\n y is \n{1}'.format(x[:5], y[:5])

# make the plots
plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig("myfig.pdf")
#+END_SRC

* Finally, show the plot

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session jk :exports results :results file
"myfig.pdf"
#+END_SRC
```

Is there anyway I can set this up?

Comment: Rather than looking for a lo-tech solution of waiting a certain period of time for a process to finish, you really should consider looking for a more sophisticated approach that waits for a process to complete successfully before proceeding to the next part of the function ...  This is normally done with a `set-process-sentinel` ...  Alternatively, you may be interested in `run-with-idle-timer` rather than a sleep per se.

Comment: This question is unclear to me.  Can you please add an example?

Comment: @phils I think this is a continuation of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41336/src-python-in-org-mode-indentationerror-unexpected-indent#comment64924_41336 There is an example there. Pityingly that example does not show the problem for me. But that may depend on the computer where it is executed.

Comment: Edited with a minimal example.  
So essentially, this code works. 
However if do a (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)  then the plot won't show on the pdf after C-c C-e l p.

@Tobias many thanks for the good points, but as noted in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html , sentinel runs only while Emacs is waiting... so that wont work i guess. 
I will investigate run-with-idle-timer: I am not seeing how I can use for multiple code blocks in one org file.

Comment: @CyBu - A few questions: Have you tried forcing the plot to draw with `plt.draw()` before calling `plt.savefig("myfig.pdf")` and then calling `plt.close()` afterwards to force file to close? Also why do you need the 2 blocks when you could just combine into one? Does the problem go away if you use a combined src block?

Comment: @Melioratus - Good question: If i have the code in one single block then, I don't have the plot at all even when doing C-c C-c in the code block, so I resolved by doing 2 separate blocks...  
On plt.draw(), it does not do anything more. It looks like the issue may be that by the time the plot saves the pdf is already created. The reason I say this is that I don't even see the \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{myfig.pdf} in the .tex file. So I am guessing it is due to the fact that the pdflatex doesnot find the file and gives up waiting or looking for it.

Comment: @CyBu Thank you for your answers! Very helpful. What version of emacs, org-mode, python and matlibplot are you using?

Comment: @Melioratus:  i have OSX 10.13.4 with emacs 25.3 and org-mode 9.1.12.  Python is 3.5.2 with matplotlib 2.2.2

Comment: @Melioratus, you could reproduce the issue by changing the plt.plot() to a loop creating a large number of similar plots and saving in a for loop.  
Something like: for i in range(50): plt.savefig("myfig" + str(i) +".pdf"), then in the separate block do a "myfig48.pdf"... chances are that in the pdf file produced the graph will be missing.

Comment: On the python-side: At first remove any old `myfig.pdf`. After calling `savefig` wait with a `while`-loop with `sleep` until the pdf file exists.

Comment: @Tobias - Thanks. Tried that one, however the file may have been created in the directory in terms of space, but that does not mean the data of the plot is fully loaded there yet (I tested it using a increment every time python has to wait: it does not increment. So the file is there, just not fully saved yet). So as a result pdf still does not have the file.

Comment: Maybe, you can use the [`‘draw_event` with `fig.canvas.mpl_connect`](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) to wait exactly for the moment the figure has been drawn. Maybe pass a flag from the event handler to your `sleep`-loop as information. (Some people use `draw_event` to measure the real extent of the figure including the labels and the title and to re-size the canvas.) Note, that I don't do very much with python. I just search the net for infos about the problem.

Comment: A walk around is by running twice the C-c C-e will do the trick because the files will be already there from the first run, ready to be picked up on the second one...  Won't be too efficient if the code is long to run, but that's all i have for now